# Mechanical Touchpad Button doesn't work on MacbookPro using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: touchpad, hardware, macbook-pro

Before I upgraded my ubuntu, my clickpad works fine. I can use the hardware button nicely. But after I upgraded it, it stop working.

I have done research about my clickpad on MacbookPro. It's called bcm5974. I have also tried evtest and evemu-record with no luck. The clickpad button is not detected when I pressed it. Right now, I use touchpad emulation of clicking. It works fine, but the hardware button isn't. Do anyone know what's going on with my Ubuntu?

```
xinput list

⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer 
(2)] ⎜   ↳ bcm5974                                  id=12   [slave 
pointer  (2)] ⎣ Virtual core keyboard                       id=3    [master
keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Apple Computer, Inc. IR Receiver          id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Apple, Inc. Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad    id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Built-in iSight

xinput list-props 12

Device 'bcm5974':
    Device Enabled (151):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (153): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Tapping Enabled (286): 1
    libinput Tapping Enabled Default (287): 0
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled (288):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled Default (289):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled (290):   0
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled Default (291):   0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Enabled (292):  1, 0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Default (293):  1, 0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (294):   0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (295):   0
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled (296):    1
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled Default (297):    1
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (298):    1, 1, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (299):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (300):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Accel Speed (301): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (302): 0.000000
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (303): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (304): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (271): 1, 1
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (272):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (273):    0, 0
    Device Node (274):  "/dev/input/event7"
    Device Product ID (275):    1452, 560
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (305):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (306):   1
```

Is there something in libinput I can set-prop to enable clickpad button?

After I checked with :

> sudo libinput debug-events --verbose

the event is not detected! Is this because of the kernel?